# Debo desuscribirme del observable al hacer .subscribe del servicio desde el componente en Angular?

Tags: angular, observable

Desde mi **componente.ts** llamo a un servicio y me **suscribo** para ver la data que trae, mi pregunta es: Tengo que **desuscribirme** desde el **componente.ts?** ya que tengo entendido que el **httpClient** (del servicio) hace la desuscripcion del observable automaticamente. Desde el componente hice la desuscripcion utilizando **takeUntil** **de rxjs** pero por ahi no hace falta.

**Aca mi servicio**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
 
 export class MyApiService {

  private unsubscribe$ = new Subject<void>();
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getTravels(): Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get<Travel[]>(this.URI + 'travel');
  }

}
```

**Aca el componente.ts donde llamo al servicio**

```js
import { Component, OnDestroy, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { MyApiService } from './../services/http/my-api.service';

constructor(
    public myApiService: MyApiService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getTravels();
  }
  
  getTravels() {
    this.myApiService
      .getTravels()
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$))
      .subscribe((res) => {
        this.travels = res;
      });
  }
  
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.unsubscribe$.next();
    this.unsubscribe$.complete();
  }
```

Comment: No es necesario. Angular destruye la suscripción cuando esta finaliza con complete, pero esto no aplica siempre. Puede que los datos aun no lleguen cuando el usuario abandona tu componente, de manera que seguirá pendiente la resolución del observable. Aunque no es un comportamiento común, puede pasar y la suscripción continuara activa hasta que se resuelva.

Answer (score 2):

Cuando el observable es de un solo uso, una buena práctica usar el pipe *take*:

```
source.pipe(take(1));
```

De esta forma, al terminar, se cierra la suscripción automáticamente.

Si los datos solo los vamos a mostrar en el html, una buena práctica es usar el pipe *async*.

```
<span>{{source | async }}</span>
```

De esta forma, cuando se deje de mostrar ese HTML, Angular cerrará la suscripción automáticamente y además será más optimo repintando.